# How does dot product work in matrix algebra?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, partial-derivative

I am working on a weighted minimization problem.  Without the weights, the error function can be expressed as $e^T e$.  With weights, $e$ first need to element-wise multiple by $w$, then the same formula applies: $(w \circ e)^T (w \circ e)$.  How do I express it in pure matrix form (without the $\circ$).  The $\circ$ operation is giving me a lot of trouble in trying to derive a derivative of a chained function on a set of parameters.  It would be better if it's a matrix whose diagonal is $w_i e_i$, and 0 elsewhere; or a vector of $w_i e_i$.

For the weighted minimization problem, I have
$$g = e^T e, \; e_i = w_i u_i, \; u = h(X)$$
  where
$$u, w, e \in \mathbb{R}_{m}, \; X \in \mathbb{R}_{n}, \;
  g: \mathbb{R}_{m} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}_{1}, \; 
  h: \mathbb{R}_{n} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}_{m} $$ 
I want to find $\frac{dg(X)}{dX}$.  I think this should be in $\mathbb{R}_{n}^T$. Applying the chain rule in the single variable manner,
$$ \frac{dg(X)}{dX} = 2 e \frac{de}{du} \frac{du}{dX} $$
$$ \frac{dg(u)}{du} \in \mathbb{R}_{m}^T, \; \frac{du}{dX} \in \mathbb{R}_{mn} $$
The sizes of the matrices don't foot because $e \frac{de}{du}$ should be $e \circ \frac{de}{du}$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One nice way to make your function into a matrix product is to define the diagonal matrix
$$
W = \pmatrix{w_1&&\\&\ddots&\\&&w_n}
$$
We then have
$$
(w \circ e)^T(w \circ e) = (We)^T (We) = e^T W^TWe =\\
e^T \pmatrix{|w_1|^2&&\\&\ddots&\\&&|w_n|^2} e
$$

Comment: Ohhhhh, same answer!

Answer (score 1):

Note that $$ (w \circ e)^\top (w \circ e) = e^\top W e$$
where $W = \mathrm{diag}^{-1}(w_1^2, \ldots, w_n^2)$ and $\circ$ denotes Hadamard (or Schur) product.